# bash html highlighting?

Tags: bash, html, syntax-highlighting

I work in bash/xterm a lot, and do a lot of filtering of HTML. What I was wondering is if there is a simple way to highlight html to stdout?

Something like:

`$ cat file.html | [some html highlighting utility]`

Would output syntax colored HTML to standard out, assuming $TERM is xterm-color or xterm-256color.

Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and it's called [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/), I used to run `highlight -q -s vim-dark -M file` (`-M` means `--xterm256`)

There is another option, [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) if you are Python fan, you will like it. You can just run `pygmentize example.html`.

Answer (score 0):

use this tool, worked great for me

https://github.com/theZiz/aha

```
cat file.html | /path/to/compiled-aha
```